# How to use Findroot in a loop

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Consider:

```
i = 0.1;
While[
 i < 0.9,
 y[x_] :=
  y /. FindRoot[{u/(1 - u) (x + Log[y]) - 1 /. u -> i}, {y, 3}];
 Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 4}];
 i = i + 0.1]
```

I want to draw graphs for y[x] for different i's in one graph. Then based on the top answer, I write the following code for further progame:

```
Clear[f, y, i]

f[x_] := Quiet[y /. FindRoot[i (x + Log[y])/(1 - i) - 1, {y, 3}]]

output = {};

i = 0.1;
While[i < 0.9,
 AppendTo[output, 
  g := x /. Last[FindMaximum[-f[x]^(1/4) - 1/f[x], {x, 3}]];
  t = Table[{i, g}, {i, 0, 1, 0.1}];
  h = Table[{i, f[g]}, {i, 0, 1, 0.1}];
 i = i + 0.05]

ListLinePlot[{t,h}]
```

But I cannot plot h.

Comment: One-space indent? Please, no.

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear[f, y, i]

f[x_] := Quiet[y /. FindRoot[i (x + Log[y])/(1 - i) - 1, {y, 3}]]

output = {};

i = 0.1;
While[i < 0.9,
  AppendTo[output, Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 4, 0.1}]];
  i = i + 0.1]

ListLinePlot[output,
 PlotLegends -> Map["i = " <> ToString[#] &, Range[8]/10.]]
```

[image]

With `PlotRange -> All` to include the first curve in the plot.

```
ListLinePlot[output,
 PlotLegends -> Map["i = " <> ToString[#] &, Range[8]/10.],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Or use log plot

```
ListLogPlot[output,
 PlotLegends -> Map["i = " <> ToString[#] &, Range[8]/10.],
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Also, super-cautious approach, discarding any points that the root finder had trouble with.

```
Clear[f, y, i]

f[x_] := Quiet[
  ans = y /. FindRoot[i (x + Log[y])/(1 - i) - 1, {y, 3},
     MaxIterations -> 1000];
  If[Length[$MessageList] > 0, "discard", ans]]

output = {};

i = 0.1;
While[i < 0.9,
  AppendTo[output, Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 4, 0.1}]];
  i = i + 0.1]

ListLogPlot[output /. {_, _String} -> Nothing,
 PlotLegends -> Map["i = " <> ToString[#] &, Range[8]/10.]]
```

[image]

***Additional question***

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[(i = #;
     Cases[Table[{x, -f[x]^(1/4) - 1/f[x]}, {x, -3, 6, 0.01}],
      {_, _Real}]) & /@ (Range[8]/10.),
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 6}, {-14, 0}}],
 ListPlot[(i = #;
     MaximalBy[
      Cases[Table[{x, -f[x]^(1/4) - 1/f[x]}, {x, -3, 6, 0.01}],
       {_, _Real}], Last]) & /@ (Range[8]/10.),
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 6}, {-14, 0}}, PlotStyle -> Black]]
```

[image]

```
{i = #,
   MaximalBy[
     Cases[Table[{x, -f[x]^(1/4) - 1/f[x]}, {x, -3, 6, 0.01}],
      {_, _Real}], Last][[1, 2]]} & /@ (Range[8]/10.)
```

> ```
> {{0.1, -2.16679}, {0.2, -1.64939}, {0.3, -1.64939}, {0.4, -1.64939},
>  {0.5, -1.64939}, {0.6, -1.64939}, {0.7, -1.64938}, {0.8, -1.64939}}
> ```

The maximum `z` value is basically constant.

Comment: thank you very much!! If you don't mind, can I ask another question? I want to find the maximum for this function: -f[x]^(1/4) - 1/f[x] at each i.  i.e., for a given i, z=x/. Last[FindMaximum[ -f[x]^(1/4) - 1/f[x],{x,3}]]. And I want to draw a graph of z over i.

Comment: `FindMaximum` doesn't like that much!  Using `Table` again ...  (see edit)

Answer (score 3):

One way might be

```
root[x_?NumericQ, i_] := y /. First@FindRoot[i/(1 - i) (x + Log[y]) - 1, {y, 3}]
Last@Reap@Do[
   Sow@Plot[root[x, i], {x, 0, 4}], {i, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}
   ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

The roots can be found directly with `Solve`.

```
sol = Simplify[
  SolveValues[{u/(1 - u) (x + Log[y]) - 1 == 0, 0 < u < 1}, y, Reals], 
  0 < u < 1]

(* {E^(-1 + 1/u - x)} *)

Plot[
 Evaluate@
  Table[Tooltip[sol[[1]], u], {u, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1}],
 {x, 0, 4},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[
   LineLegend[Range[0.1, 0.8, 0.1],
    LegendLabel -> Style[u, 12, Bold]],
   {0.9, 0.57}],
 PlotLabel ->
  StringForm["``", u/(1 - u) (x + Log[y]) - 1 == 0]]
```

[image]

The line for `u == 0.1` is off the top of the `Plot`. To show it, all of the other lines would be drawn on top of each other. Consequently, use "Log" scaling.

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@
  Table[Tooltip[sol[[1]], u], {u, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1}],
 {x, 0, 4},
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
 PlotLegends ->
  LineLegend[Range[0.1, 0.8, 0.1],
   LegendLabel -> Style[u, 12, Bold]],
 PlotLabel ->
  StringForm["``", u/(1 - u) (x + Log[y]) - 1 == 0],
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]